# Calling an action in the mapStateProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can I call an action in the mapStateProps, in case the state doesn't exist yet?, I'm wondering if it doesn't affect the performance, and an unintentional re rendering.

Or can I do It using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), calling the action instead, when creating the selection.

Or do you have any suggestion on how to do it? Thanks

```html
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {
  return {
    reviewContentDetails: state.reviewsReducer.reviewContentDetails || callAnAction(ownProps._id),
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(reviewsAction, dispatch),
  };
}
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do. When my state doesn't exist, it will take the intial state (provided in my code) and use this one. Of course you can call an action (using dispatch). Can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: I have added a sample code @Larce

Answer (score 1):

For Action you must made in **mapDispatchToProps**

Eg:**Here is Test Component**

```
const Test = ({onclickTest}) =>{
     return <div>  
        <button onClick ={onclickTest}>Test Button</button> 
            </div>
```

Then you define your Action in function  **mapDispatchToProps**

```
const mapDispatchToProps= {onclickTest : yourOnclickTestAction}
```

Finally you can connect with **Redux**

```
export default connect (
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```

PS: For **mapStateToProps** I think you should work with selector. It's easier to fix for feature. Hope it is helpful for you ^^

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not.  A `mapStateToProps` function should *only* extract values from the state tree and return them as a new object.  It should *never* do any asynchronous work, or start any other behavior.

If you need to call a function based on changes in values, do that in `componentWillReceiveProps` in your React component.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but it will probably cause much more problems than you intend to solve. State is most easily and clearly initialized in reducers, and that is pattern which is used.

If you need to perform some actions once, (like dispatching async fetch, or similar), it is best to perform it in componentDidMount.